# How to make GpuRay visible by the cameras?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I want to project a laser line on my scene. I've tried to the steps sugested in [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9807/how-can-i-simulate-a-line-laser/), but the laser being project behind objects is not suitable for my application.

Then I tried to use a GpuRay sensor and enabled it with the tag `<visualize>true</visualize>` on my SDF. In fact, the laser rays are showed on Gazebo GUI, but they are as supposed to, they are not captured by cameras. I would like however to modify this behavior to being able to see it by the cameras.

[image: image description]

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it? The class "LaserVisual" could me help somehow?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21315/how-to-make-gpuray-visible-by-the-cameras?/) by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The camera can't see the laser because we explicitly exclude "GUI visuals" from sensor view, and allow them on the user camera view.

One way to let your sensors see GUI visuals could be to create a sensor plugin for your camera and then alter its visibility flag, something like this:

`camera->OgreViewPort()->setVisibilityMask(GZ_VISIBILITY_ALL & ~GZ_VISIBILITY_SELECTABLE);`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2